# Erro envio de e-mail PHP-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, pessoal!

Estou estudando PHP-Laravel (sou nova na linguagem tb). Eu estou precisando fazer um envio de e-mail, porém está me apresentando o erro

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Mails' not found in file C:\dev\github\phpLaravel\blog\app\Http\Controllers\ContatoFaleConoscoController.php on line 28

Eu pesquisei e encontrei a solução de usar o facade utilizando o `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

Mesmo assim o erro persiste. Quando eu mando renderizar o conteúdo do e-mail, funciona normalmente. Só no envio que dá esse problema. Vejam meu código abaixo:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ContatoFaleConosco;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use App\Mail\ContatoFaleConoscoMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContatoFaleConoscoController extends Controller
{
    private $app;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->app= App::getFacadeRoot();
    }

    public function send(Request $request){
        $model = $this->app->make('App\Models\ContatoFaleConosco');

        $model->assunto = $request->input('assunto');
        $model->mensagem = $request->input('mensagem');
        $model->remetente->nome = $request->input('remetente.nome');
        $model->remetente->email = $request->input('remetente.email');

        Mails::to($model->remetente->email)->send(new ContatoFaleConoscoMail($model));
        return (new ContatoFaleConoscoMail($model))->render();
    }
}
```

Mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\ContatoFaleConosco;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContatoFaleConoscoMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $model;
    public $nomeRemetente;

    public function __construct(ContatoFaleConosco $contatoFaleConosco)
    {
        $this->model = $contatoFaleConosco;
        $this->nomeRemetente = $this->model->remetente->nome;

    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contato-fale-conosco')
                ->from($this->model->remetente->email, $this->nomeRemetente);
    }
}
```

Muito obrigada aí

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada na documentação e vi `Mail::to` para enviar, você usa `Mails::to` não sei se é a chamada correta do método.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta o `use Mail`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Mail;
```

Comment: Obrigada, eu vi depois que eu estava usando Mails no lugar de Mail. Panguei, to aprendendo laravel ainda.